# 2 contentEditable containers inside each other; possible bug?

Tags: html, contenteditable

`<div contenteditable="true">`
    `<div contenteditable="true">hi</div>`
`</div>`

If you try to edit the inner contentEditable div, which is practically when you click on it, you'll get stuck to it and can't insert anything outside it unless you remove the child contentEditable by backspace. Clicking outside the inner div doesn't help even if the outer div is bigger. This happens on FF & Webkit. 
Is this a bug or is it the way it's used to work? Any solution to change this behavior? e.g. when you click outside the inner div, you start to edit the outer one.

Cheers
Parsa

Answer (score 2):

I got the same here,

```
<div contenteditable="true"> father
    <div contenteditable="false"> child </div>
</div>
```

If I select the **child div** I am able to **delete** the text **child** but not **edit** it.
The text **father** I'm able to delete and edit.

I think the logic is correct and make sense. If you change the child div to true then you can delete and edit the tag.

the problem is: you can not see the div tag father and child when the content was deleted. then you only suppose the first one is father div and the second is child.

Good post!

Comment: Yes but logically, there should be an option to have both of them set to `contenteditable="true"` and be able to edit parent and child separately.

Comment: it happens because the first div tag, logically everything else inside will be changed.
IF I Have a div tag, and inside I have a <h1> tag or a <p> tag, then if you don't want the <p> tag to be edited then, especify with contenteditable="false" It will not be longer avaliable to edit, but yes it will be able to delete. This is how it works! If have a bug, when I specify false in contenteditable and it is able to delete.. then we found a bug. Yeah!?